# Tailwind custom color themes not detected in Angular 13

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I defined a custom color theme called "brand" in my **tailwind.config.js** file like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  prefix: '',
  purge: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    content: [
      "./src/**/*.html",
      "./src/**/*.ts",
    ]
  },
  darkMode: 'class', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        transparent: 'transparent',
        brand: {
          light: '#047bc1',
          DEFAULT: '#047bc1',
          dark: '#047bc1'
        },
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
};
```

Then I use the custom key in my html template like this:

```html
<div class="w-full h-16 pl-6 pr-5 bg-white border-4 border-brand rounded-full flex justify-between items-center relative">
  <input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search"
         class="appearance-none w-full outline-none focus:outline-none active:outline-none">
  <button type="submit" class="ml-1 outline-none focus:outline-none active:outline-none">
    <svg fill="none" stroke="brand" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="3"
         viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="w-6 h-6">
      <path d="M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z"></path>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

As you can see I used the classes: "border-brand" and "brand" in the code. I didn't find any examples of this in the documentation and maybe there could be the problem, but when rendering the template it didn't get the color defined in the config:

[image]

Comment: Where do you use tailwind-CSS? (Vue.js React,.)
Do other properties OK?

Comment: Hello! I'm using it with Angular 13. Defaults properties work as spected (text-blue-400, border-red, etc).

Comment: Plz create another angular app and install tailwind and check then add custom color after this, check your project width new test app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it with Angular 13 and sometimes you need to reload your project to get new settings, this happens with angular and visual studio.

this code is right.

```
    brand: {
      light: '#047bc1',
      DEFAULT: '#047bc1',
      dark: '#047bc1'
    },
```

[image]